# Oracle to SQL Server Conversion help: sys_connect_by_path, listagg, regexp

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016, oracle-11g

I've been tasked with converting a process from Oracle to Sql Server 2012.

I've converted most of the query over to SQL Server but am having a hard time translating over these queries to SQL Server logic.

**sys_connect_by_path example:**

```
SELECT sys_connect_by_path(field1, '/') || '/' || field2 || '/' path
  FROM data
 WHERE connect_by_isleaf = 1 connect BY prior field2 = field1 start
 WITH field1 NOT IN (SELECT field2 FROM data)
```

I know that I need to use a CTE for this example (possibly recursive) but I can't seem to get my logic correct

**regexp example:**

```
select field1, field2, regexp_substr(path, '[^/]+', 1, column_value) elem
  from grouped,
table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
connect by level <= regexp_count(path,'/')) as sys.odciNumberList))
where regexp_substr(path, '[^/]+', 1, column_value) is not null
```

**listagg example:**

```
select field1, field2,
       dense_rank() over (order by listagg(elem,',') within group (order by elem)) grp
  from split
group by field1, field2
```

From what I understand, listagg in SQL is done by the STUFF function. That seems simple enough to understand but in this case I'm not sure how I make it work

Could I get some pointers?

Comment: Are you using SSMA For Oracle?  It's got a bunch of conversion logic and compatibility functions already implemented.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54258  Also newer versions of SQL might make this easier.

Comment: I tried that but I do not have enough access to the database and I cannot get any additional access.

Comment: You can use the "Scripts" functionality in SSMA to paste and convert individual statements, or you can use a local Oracle instance you control to work on the schema and code migration.

Comment: Thanks David. Didn't think about creating a local Oracle instance. I'm doing that now.